# Adding a matrix to a list

Tags: r, list, matrix

I am an R newbie. I am trying to add a matrix to a list before returning it from a function.

```
a <- matrix(4,4,4)
x <- list(l=1, m=2)
x["n"] <- a
```

The above ends with the following warning message and only one number from the matrix gets added to the list.

```
Warning message:
In x["n"] <- a :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

How can I do this? It would be nice if I some how don't have to specify the dimensions of the matrix before hand.

Comment: Welcome ! You need to use x$n <- a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$` extraction:

```
> x$n <- a
> x
$l
[1] 1

$m
[1] 2

$n
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    4    4    4    4
[2,]    4    4    4    4
[3,]    4    4    4    4
[4,]    4    4    4    4
```

Or `[[` extraction:

```
> x$n <- NULL
> x[["n"]] <- a
> x
$l
[1] 1

$m
[1] 2

$n
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    4    4    4    4
[2,]    4    4    4    4
[3,]    4    4    4    4
[4,]    4    4    4    4
```

Comment: I know that `$` or `[[]]` can be used to get the elements directly instead of a list representation while referencing. But how does this work during assignment. Can you point me to some documentation regarding this?

Comment: The [basic extraction document](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html) is a good read. For list-like objects, it only discusses the `$<-` and `[[<-` assignment methods, both of which are primitives.