# How can I add another matrix to a created list?

Tags: r, matrix

I have downloaded the following list:

[image]

[image]

Which comes from the package `RGAP`.

```
install.packages("RGAP")
library(RGAP)
data("gap")
```

How can I add data from an Excel file which contains the same variables as the countries in `gap`? This is the data, `espanya`, I need to import:

```
      Any        l   ahours     etd      et        k        i ur...8      pop     popw   popact    popun  actrate ur...14  wtotal     eet     etc
[1,] 2001 30386541 1762.070 17244.8 17244.8 2008.095 176.8961   10.6 40766.05 31852.92 19289.49 2044.685 60.55799    10.6 336.894 14370.9 16459.4
[2,] 2002 31168059 1763.647 17672.5 17672.5 2088.746 183.4316   11.5 41423.52 32345.96 19968.93 2296.427 61.73546    11.5 358.651 14783.0 16830.2
[3,] 2003 32002228 1754.633 18238.7 18238.7 2175.977 194.9558   11.5 42196.23 32887.79 20608.70 2370.001 62.66368    11.5 379.836 15356.1 17272.6
[4,] 2004 32896138 1739.901 18906.9 18906.9 2266.818 203.8939   11.0 42859.17 33346.35 21243.71 2336.808 63.70626    11.0 405.363 15954.9 17720.2
[5,] 2005 33964852 1723.719 19704.4 19704.4 2366.623 218.5119    9.1 43662.61 33931.44 21677.01 1972.608 63.88473     9.1 435.033 16704.0 18325.0
[6,] 2006 35152762 1713.741 20512.3 20512.3 2476.252 234.7343    8.5 44360.52 34359.57 22417.81 1905.514 65.24474     8.5 471.451 17492.7 18966.5
     etc_ass wage_worker    winfl     part   pconsp     ngdp       gdp  gdpdefl     prod       ws     nulc       tfp     cubs
[1,] 13779.7    23.44279       NA 60.55799 74.43252  700.993  909.6837 77.05898 52.75119 48.05954 82.58245 -7.047814 80.94351
[2,] 14161.1    24.26104 3.490423 61.73546 76.44457  749.552  934.5270 80.20657 52.88029 47.84871 85.25627 -7.051159 79.57347
[3,] 14605.3    24.73519 1.954341 62.66368 78.89058  802.266  962.3938 83.36151 52.76658 47.34539 87.10979 -7.053263 79.60757
[4,] 15008.1    25.40680 2.715226 63.70626 81.70935  859.437  992.4472 86.59775 52.49127 47.16611 89.94430 -7.054735 79.79350
[5,] 15584.5    26.04364 2.506570 63.88473 84.45069  927.357 1028.6918 90.14916 52.20620 46.91106 92.70227 -7.054728 80.44729
[6,] 16205.5    26.95130 3.485140 65.24474 87.50621 1003.823 1070.8963 93.73671 52.20752 46.96555 95.93065 -7.052713 79.94607
```

Comment: I have imported my data from Excel. Its class: "mts"    "ts"     "matrix"``

Comment: in that case you can simply do `gap$Marialand <- mytimeseries`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a matrix to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459120/adding-a-matrix-to-a-list)

Comment: What Allan told answered my question! Thanks!